# Loading in numbers from a file containing whitespace to a 2d integer array

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, multidimensional-array

I have a file of numbers, laid out in a 20x20 grid (there exists a line break every line). I'm trying to figure out how I could load this into a 2d array of ints in plain C?

[Here's the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmzRn.png)

[image]

[Here's a link to the actual text file](http://pastebin.com/vwzP88x0)

My File I/O knowledge as it is is already very shaky and kindergarten level at best.

Comment: Then get back to tutorials/books and search the web. There are astronomical numbers of examples of C file I/O all over the place. Try something. Post here when you have _specific_ problems.

Comment: Why not read it in as an array of strings?

Comment: You'll get a better response if you try have a go at a solution yourself.  Try looking into [fscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf), write some code then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Hint: Use [fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) and [strtol](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fscanf version**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    int i, j;
    int data[20][20];

    if(NULL==(fp=fopen("data.txt","r"))){
        perror("file can't open");
        return -1;
    }
/*  slower than fgets and strtol
    for(i=0;i<20;++i)
        for(j=0;j<20;++j)
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &data[i][j]);
*/
    for(i=0;i<20;++i)//little difference
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d"
                   "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
            &data[i][0],&data[i][1],&data[i][2],&data[i][3],&data[i][4],
            &data[i][5],&data[i][6],&data[i][7],&data[i][8],&data[i][9],
            &data[i][10],&data[i][11],&data[i][12],&data[i][13],&data[i][14],
            &data[i][15],&data[i][16],&data[i][17],&data[i][18],&data[i][19]);
    fclose(fp);
    //pickup check 
    printf("%d\n", data[5][4]);//99
    printf("%d\n", data[19][19]);//48

    return 0;
}
```

**fgets and strtol version**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    int i, j, wk;
    int data[20][20];
    char buff[64], *p, *endp;

    if(NULL==(fp=fopen("data.txt","r"))){
        perror("file can't open");
        return -1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<20;++i){
        fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp);
        for(j=0, p=buff;j<20;++j, p=endp){
            wk = (int)strtol(p, &endp, 10);
            if(*endp == ' ' || *endp == '\n' || *endp == '\0'){
                data[i][j] = wk;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //pickup check 
    printf("%d\n", data[5][4]);//99
    printf("%d\n", data[19][19]);//48
    return 0;
}
```

**not use fscanf or fgets and strtol version. (maybe most fast, but situation is limited.)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    int data[20][20];
    int wk, wk2, *ip, *endp = &data[19][19]+1;
    char buff[1280]={0}, *cp;

    fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
    fread(buff, sizeof(buff), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    ip=&data[0][0];
    wk = 0;
    for(cp=buff;ip!=endp;++cp){
        if(isdigit(*cp)){
            wk2 = wk << 1;
            wk = (wk2 << 2) + wk2 + (*cp -'0');
        } else {
            *ip++ = wk;
            wk = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**note:every version of these three has only for a very short time of an unmeasurable.**

**it is meaningless about slow and fast, case of reading the data of 20 x 20.**

Comment: Two suggestions: `perror("fopen")` instead of `perror("file can't open")`, and it will be faster if you read entire lines with `fgets` and then `strtol` instead of `fscanf`

Comment: That first version, with the long fscanf format string, should be taken out and shot.

Comment: The longer the format seems to need in a short period of time.